# Counting fully bound holes in a bitmap image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, bitmap, computer-vision

I have a monochrome bitmap image, and I wish to find fully bound holes in the image. Only holes that are fully bound by black pixels should be included:

```
0000000000   
0001111100   
0010000010   
0001000110   
0000111100   
0000000000
```

has one hole

but

```
0100000010
0100000110
0011111100
0000000000
```

would have 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to [CCL (Connected Component Labelling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling). If you invert the bitmap then you are just looking for 4-connected blobs which do not touch the edge of the image frame.